# How to remove the whitespace in paragraph

Tags: html, css

I am trying to remove the whitespace in the following paragraph. Even though there is no white space in the code, there appears a white space in the output.

Here is the code

```
 <p class="doctor-locations">
   LOCATION  :VIKRAM HOSPITAL,
   MANIPAL HOSPITAL, CLINIC
 </p>
```

Here is the css

```
.doctor-locations {
            font-size: 11px;
            color: $button-violet;
            font-weight: 600;
            text-align: justify;
            margin-left: 15%;   
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }
```

[image: Expected output]

[image: Actual output]

Comment: Can you provide a working snippet, codepen or jsfiddle?

Comment: That's caused by `text-align:justify`...if you don't want it...don't use it.

Comment: But everything has to start from left according to that design, so is there any alternative to the justify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `justify` on the `text-align` is what is doing it. You can set it to `left`:

Adding a `<br/>` will allow you to move items to the next line that you wish.

```css
.doctor-locations {
  font-size: 11px;
  color: $button-violet;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<p class="doctor-locations">
  LOCATION: VIKRAM HOSPITAL, <br>MANIPAL HOSPITAL, CLINIC
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try that?

```
<p class="doctor-locations">
LOCATION&nbsp;:VIKRAM HOSPITAL, MANIPAL HOSPITAL, CLINIC
</p>
```

If you want a return (another line) after HOSPITAL, put the "br /" between HOSPITAL, and MANIPAL. Like this:

```
<p class="doctor-locations">
LOCATION&nbsp;:VIKRAM HOSPITAL,<br />MANIPAL HOSPITAL, CLINIC
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

just add `<br />` after each line and set `text-align: left` in css